# translate query from Oracle to Postgres

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, oracle

I need to translate this query from Oracle to Postgres:

```
select
case when (not regexp_like(upper(location),'^[0-9]{1,5} [A-Z]') or not regexp_like(upper(location),'^[0-9]{1,5}.* [a-z]') or regexp_like(upper(location),'^[0-9]{1,5}')) and regexp_like(upper(modelname),'CEDMI') then '74'
when (not regexp_like(upper(location),'^[0-9]{1,5} [A-Z]') or not regexp_like(upper(location),'^[0-9]{1,5}.* [a-z]') or regexp_like(upper(location),'^[0-9]{1,5}')) and regexp_like(upper(modelname),'CEDNA') then '768'
when (not regexp_like(upper(location),'^[0-9]{1,5} [A-Z]') or not regexp_like(upper(location),'^[0-9]{1,5}.* [a-z]') or regexp_like(upper(location),'^[0-9]{1,5}')) and regexp_like(upper(modelname),'CEDRM') then '598'
when (not regexp_like(upper(modelname),'CEDMI') or not regexp_like(upper(modelname),'CEDNA') or not regexp_like(upper(modelname),'CEDRM')) and (regexp_like(upper(location),'^[A-Z]') or location is null) then null
else location
end as LOCATION
from stagingarea.ENEL_TLC_T_DEVICE
```

can someone help me?

thanks in advance for your attention and support

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP)  the equivalent to `regexp_like` is `similar to` or the `~` operator

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for reply. do you mean something like this:

Comment: `select location,modelname,
case 
when ((upper(location) NOT SIMILAR TO '^[0-9]{1,5} [A-Z]' or upper(location) NOT SIMILAR TO '^[0-9]{1,5}.* [a-z]' or upper(location) SIMILAR TO '^[0-9]{1,5}') and upper(modelname) SIMILAR TO 'CEDMI') then '74'
else location
end as LOCATION
from stagingarea.ENEL_TLC_T_DEVICE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postgres the operateur `~` performs a regex comparison as thus replaces the Oracle function `regexp_like()`. Your query therefore becomes.
I would like to alert your attention that the test `not  upper(location) ~ '^[0-9]{1,5}.* [a-z]'` will always be true because the application of `upper()` makes it impossible to match `[a-z]`.

> ```
> create table ENEL_TLC_T_DEVICE(
> location varchar(100),
> modelname varchar(100)   );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into ENEL_TLC_T_DEVICE (location, modelname) values
> ('12A','CEDMI'),
> ('12A','CEDRM'),
> ('12A','CEDNA'),
> ('12AA','CEDMI'),
> ('12AA','CEDRM'),
> ('12AA','CEDNA'),
> (null,null);
> ```
>
> ```
> 7 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select
> location, 
> modelname,
> case when (not  upper(location) ~ '^[0-9]{1,5} [A-Z]' or not  upper(location) ~ '^[0-9]{1,5}.* [a-z]' or  upper(location) ~ '^[0-9]{1,5}') and  upper(modelname) ~ 'CEDMI' then '74'
> when (not  upper(location) ~ '^[0-9]{1,5} [A-Z]' or not  upper(location) ~ '^[0-9]{1,5}.* [a-z]' or  upper(location) ~ '^[0-9]{1,5}') and  upper(modelname) ~ 'CEDNA' then '768'
> when (not  upper(location) ~ '^[0-9]{1,5} [A-Z]' or not  upper(location) ~ '^[0-9]{1,5}.* [a-z]' or  upper(location) ~ '^[0-9]{1,5}') and  upper(modelname) ~ 'CEDRM' then '598'
> when (not  upper(modelname) ~ 'CEDMI' or not  upper(modelname) ~ 'CEDNA' or not  upper(modelname) ~ 'CEDRM') and  ( upper(location) ~ '^[A-Z]' or location is null) then null
> else location
> end as LOCATION
> from ENEL_TLC_T_DEVICE;
> ```

> ```
> location | modelname | location
> :------- | :-------- | :-------
> 12A      | CEDMI     | 74      
> 12A      | CEDRM     | 598     
> 12A      | CEDNA     | 768     
> 12AA     | CEDMI     | 74      
> 12AA     | CEDRM     | 598     
> 12AA     | CEDNA     | 768     
> null     | null      | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=500c0458df388904333cf3b3cceee401)*